# PyZMQ PUSH socket does not block on send()

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

The `ZMQ_PUSH`section in [ZMQ socket documentation](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-socket) say that calling `send()` on PUSH socket, which has no downstream nodes should block until at least one node becomes available.

However, running the following code does not seem to block on `send()`. Also, the process does not exit until I run a matching PULL socket and receive the messages:

```
import zmq
import time

zmq_context = zmq.Context()
print '> Creating a PUSH socket'
sender = zmq_context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
print '> Connecting'
sender.connect('tcp://localhost:%s' % 5555)
print '> Sending'
sender.send('message 1')
print '> Sent'
```

Output:

```
Creating a PUSH socket
Connecting
Sending
Sent
```

Am I missing something, or is this a bug in PyZmq?

*Version Info: Windows 7, Python 2.7, PyZMQ 14.0.1*

**EDIT** 
After some fiddling, it seems that if I replace **`sender.connect('tcp://localhost:5555)`** with **`sender.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555)`**, it works as expected. Not sure how its related, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HWM condition is not hit in the example you gave. When you open a connection, a buffer is created even before the peer connection is established. HWM is only hit when this buffer is full. For example:

```
import zmq

zmq_context = zmq.Context()
print '> Creating a PUSH socket'
sender = zmq_context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
sender.hwm = 1
print '> Connecting'
sender.connect('tcp://localhost:%s' % 5555)
for i in range(3):
    print '> Sending', i
    sender.send('message %i' % i)
    print '> Sent', i
```

Where HWM is set to 1. In this case, the first message will be buffered, and the second send will block until the first message is actually transmitted.

Comment: as far as I understand, the relevant HMW in this case is the downstream node's, not the pushing node's. Moreover, if instead of `sender.connect('tcp://localhost:%s' % 5555)` I do `sender.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:%s' % 5555)`, it works as expected.

Comment: That's because buffers are created per-peer. `sock.connect` creates one pipe immediately on the connector, and another on the binder, if/when it arrives. `bind`, on the other hand, doesn't create any pipes until a peer connects, and it creates more pipes as more peers connect. To put it another way: the initial condition of `connect` is 'one empty buffer available, HWM condition not met,' while the initial condition of `bind` is 'zero buffers available, HWM condition met.'

Comment: should I use bind() or connect() in this case then?

Comment: You shouldn't let the HWM behavior dictate whether you want bind or connect - typically one of your two services either starts first, lives longer, or is a singleton, while the other may start/stop later, more frequently, or have multiple simultaneous instances. The former should bind, while the latter connects. If one of your peers can be considered more conventionally "a server," that is likely the one to bind.