# ZeroMQ - Dealer Socket Does not Block on Send If it Connects Instead of Bind?

Tags: c#, zeromq

I have a question using ZeroMQ with Dealer Sockets connecting to a peer instead of binding and having a peer connect to it.

Here is in an example (This is not using a public C# binding of ZeroMQ):

```
var router = context.CreateRouterSocket();
var dealer = context.CreateDealerSocket();

var endpoint = ZeroTcpEndpoint.CreateLoopback(9000);
dealer.Connect(endpoint);

// ...
//           
// If I don't bind the Router and I send a message on the Dealer,
// it doesn't block. It seems the message is dropped.

// router.Bind(endpoint);
dealer.SendMessage();
```

As you can see, if I have a Router Socket that I don't bind and I connect a Dealer Socket to it, `SendMessage` does not block. It seems the message is dropped.

This simulates that a Dealer only blockes on `SendMessage`, as per the documentation, **if it binds and has a peer connect to it, and not when it itself connects to a peer.**

Basically what I am trying to achieve is avoid having the message dropped if the peer suddenly goes offline for whatever reason and since there is no way to tell the difference between a dropped message and a sent message except through blocking when there is no peer, I thought a Dealer would be the best option.

If I can't do it with a Dealer though, as observed here, is there an alternative method I can do? There is a question here that observes something similar in the Python binding ([PyZMQ PUSH socket does not block on send()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21759094/pyzmq-push-socket-does-not-block-on-send)) and it basically recommends that I set the Send High Watermark to 1. What are the pitfalls if I do that?

Thanks.